# Xamarin forms want to disable the button of the tab bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working in a application on Xamarin Forms . I have a tabbed page , i want to disable the button/icon that I click in that tab bar . Because in my Tabbed page i have some navigation page I don't want they click the icon of the tabbed page to go back ( To navigate back in the navigation page).

Thanks

Comment: set NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False" in ContentPage tag

Comment: In general, We will hide the tabbar rather than disable the button when push to page in the navigation , the tabbar only appears in the first page in ervery navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the back button completely you can set `NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"` in your page's XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             Title="Your Page">
</ContentPage>
```

You can also make this a global style that can be applied to any page you add the style to.

In App.xaml:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style x:Key="noBackButton" TargetType="ContentPage">
             <Setter Property="NavigationPage.HasBackButton" Value="False" />
         </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then add the style to your ContentPage:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Style="{StaticResource noBackButton}"
             Title="Your Page">
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I dont want to remove the back button but to disable the tabbed page icon once click

Comment: I am not sure how to disable the tab bar button. Can I ask what you are trying to achieve? Maybe a modal navigation is what you could be looking for if you want to disable the tab bar flow. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/modal/

Comment: I have some bug do to the navigation page in the tabbed page because we come back to the 1rst page via the the button of the tabbedpage so if i can disable it i can solve the bug